# How to extract float value from a string in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My string contain following value in it.

var Test = "3700 NO LAND VALUE (Lease Property) (0.10)"

Now how can i retrieve only 0.10 from above string.
output must be 0.10 not 3700

Comment: Is there a particular set of rules you can give us? for example "The last number in the string"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex

```js
var Test = "3700 NO LAND VALUE (Lease Property) (0.10)"
var regExp = /\(([0-9|.]+)\)/;  
var matches = regExp.exec(Test);
var result = matches[1];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to extract a float.

```
var re = /\d+\.\d+/g;
var test = "3700 NO LAND VALUE (Lease Property) (0.10)";
var floats = test.match(re);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like this:

```js
var Test = "3700 NO LAND VALUE (Lease Property) (0.10)";
var Regex = /([\d]+[.][\d]+)/g;

var output = Regex.exec(Test);

alert(output[1]);
```